# Closing Case in Acumatica through API

Tags: acumatica

I want to close the case in Partners Portal remotely using Web API, whenever I close the case in my (client) side. I was able to implement the code but ran into below issue.

It is changing the status and resolution of the case in Partners Portal but Close Case button is enabled and it is visible in My Open Case bucket. Please let me know if I can close the case remotely using Web API or if I am missing anything.

```html
protected virtual void CRCase_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
{
 var caseRow = (CRCase)e.Row;
 if (caseRow != null)
 {
  if (caseRow.Status == "C")  // Closed
  {
   string cloud9CaseCD = null;

   cloud9CaseCD = CRCaseForCreate.Current.CaseCD;

   string acumaticaCaseCD = string.Empty;

   CSAnswers aCCaseNoAttribute = PXSelect<CSAnswers,
     Where<CSAnswers.refNoteID, Equal<Required<CSAnswers.refNoteID>>,
     And<CSAnswers.attributeID, Equal<Required<CSAnswers.attributeID>>>>>.Select(new PXGraph(), CRCaseForCreate.Current.NoteID, "ACCASENO");
   if (aCCaseNoAttribute != null)
   {
    acumaticaCaseCD = aCCaseNoAttribute.Value;

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(acumaticaCaseCD))
    {
     SP203000WS.Screen context = new SP203000WS.Screen();
     context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
     context.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
     context.EnableDecompression = true;
     context.Timeout = 1000000;
     context.Url = "https://sso.acumatica.com/Soap/SP203000.asmx";

     PartnerPortalCreds loginCreds = GetCreds();
     string username = loginCreds.PARTPRTUSE;
     string password = loginCreds.PARTPRTPAS;

     SP203000WS.LoginResult result = context.Login(username, password);

     SP203000WS.Content CR306000 = context.GetSchema();
     context.Clear();
     SP203000WS.Content[] CR306000Content = context.Submit
      (
       new SP203000WS.Command[]
       {
        new SP203000WS.Value
        {
         Value = acumaticaCaseCD,
         LinkedCommand = CR306000.Case.CaseID
        },
         new SP203000WS.Value
        {
         Value = "C",
         LinkedCommand = new SP203000WS.Field { FieldName="Status", ObjectName="Case"}
        },
        new SP203000WS.Value
        {
         Value = "RD",
         LinkedCommand = new SP203000WS.Field { FieldName="Resolution", ObjectName="Case"}
        },
        CR306000.Actions.Submit,
        CR306000.Case.CaseID
       }
     );

     context.Logout();
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Tried below code using CloseCase Action: -

```html
protected virtual void CRCase_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
{
 var caseRow = (CRCase)e.Row;
 if (caseRow != null)
 {
  if (caseRow.Status == "C")  // Closed
  {
   string cloud9CaseCD = null;

   cloud9CaseCD = CRCaseForCreate.Current.CaseCD;

   string acumaticaCaseCD = string.Empty;

   CSAnswers aCCaseNoAttribute = PXSelect<CSAnswers,
     Where<CSAnswers.refNoteID, Equal<Required<CSAnswers.refNoteID>>,
     And<CSAnswers.attributeID, Equal<Required<CSAnswers.attributeID>>>>>.Select(new PXGraph(), CRCaseForCreate.Current.NoteID, "ACCASENO");
   if (aCCaseNoAttribute != null)
   {
    acumaticaCaseCD = aCCaseNoAttribute.Value;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(acumaticaCaseCD))
    {
     SP203010WS.Screen context = new SP203010WS.Screen();
     context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
     context.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
     context.EnableDecompression = true;
     context.Timeout = 1000000;
     context.Url = "https://sso.acumatica.com/Soap/SP203010.asmx";

     PartnerPortalCreds loginCreds = GetCreds();
     string username = loginCreds.PARTPRTUSE;
     string password = loginCreds.PARTPRTPAS;

     SP203010WS.LoginResult result = context.Login(username, password);

     SP203010WS.Content CR306000 = context.GetSchema();
     context.Clear();

     var commands1 = new SP203010WS.Command[]
     {
      new SP203010WS.Value
       {
        Value = acumaticaCaseCD,
        LinkedCommand = CR306000.Case.CaseID
       },
      new SP203010WS.Value
       {
        Value = "Yes",
        LinkedCommand = CR306000.Case.ServiceCommands.DialogAnswer, Commit = true
       },
      CR306000.Actions.CloseCase
     };

     var data = context.Submit(commands1);

     context.Logout();

    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

In the below image you can see that the case is already closed but Close Case menu button is still visible.

[image]

Close Case Confirmation Dialogbox on Partners Portal. How should I answer this dialogbox programatically while closing the case using Web API.

[image]

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution. Updated the code for CloseCase (second code snippet). This will mark the case as Pending Closure in Partners Portal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to invoke **Close** action via Web API instead of changing values of the **Status** and **Resolution** fields? As far as I know, **Close** button on the Partner Portal updates support case **Status** to ***Open*** and **Reason** to ***Pending Closure***. Then it's up to support personnel to manually close the case.

Comment: I don't see the *Close* action in Web API. That was the first action I was looking for and I didn't find it. So I am updating Status and Resolution.

Comment: I can see CloseCase action under SP203010  screen. I would try that.

Comment: Tried with CloseCase action. Added the sample code above, but seems it is not working. It is not even throwing any error and not changing status on Partners Portal. Any suggestions?

Comment: I didn't find `context.Submit(commands1);` in your sample code. Is it a typo in the code sample?

Comment: Yes, my bad, missed that statement. Updated the code. But now that I have included I am getting the confirmation dialogbox which I could have got on Partners Portal also. How should I programatically  answer that dialog box. `*System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> PX.Data.PXException: Are you sure to close this case?
at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.Submit(String screenId, IReadOnlyList`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode, PXGraph& graph, String& redirectContainerView, String& redirectScreen, Boolean mobile, Dictionary`2 viewFilters)...*`